# Reveal animation

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I've coded a reveal image animation and have stumbled across an issue when in the creation.

```css
.container{
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
  background-image: url('https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/honda_civic_type_r_honda_type_r_honda_129270_3840x2160.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  animation: 1s ease-out 0s 1 slideInFromLeft;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes slideInFromLeft {
  0% {
    transform: translatex(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translatex(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
  </div>
</div>
```

The animation seems to be working fine except for it not sliding smoothly. It seems to have a jitter of some sort.

How can I make the animation slide more smoothly?

Comment: In your snippet the animation is loading smoothly for me

Comment: note that you are using a high resolution image so the animation may end before the image load

Comment: It seems to be jittering for me. Please, can you take a look at the top left header image on this website and let me know if it is working smoothly on there for you? http://www.maximizemedia.co.uk

Comment: try to use a simple image and not a high resolution one then compare

Comment: That seems to work much better! However, I'm still stuck with the issue. I will need to use high-resolution images on my website.

Comment: now you know the issue : the big image need time to be loaded which create the issue, so you need to avoid such image

Comment: Hopefully, saving images for web through Photoshop will fix this issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, that only avoids the issue. If the net is bad the issue still happens. The proper solution is to wait for the resource to load **then** animate, so one doesn't depend on internet speed or image size. Please note I'm not saying optimizing images is bad. It's actually a **must**, IMHO. But it only covers the problem, it doesn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You could wait for the page/image to load and then trigger the animation to happen. The code below is a crude way of applying the animation class once with js.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var element = document.getElementById('img1');
    element.classList.add("show");
    element.classList.add("animate");
    
}
```

```css
.container{
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
  background-image: url('https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/honda_civic_type_r_honda_type_r_honda_129270_3840x2160.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#img1.animate{
  animation: 1s ease-out 0s 1 slideInFromLeft;
}

.show {
  opacity:1;
}

@keyframes slideInFromLeft {
  0% {
    transform: translatex(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translatex(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="img1" class="image" >
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an `<img>` element for this and remove it when it loaded, after I pass it's `src` to the `backgroundImage` of the parent, as it was already loaded:

```js
let imageDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.image img');
for (var i = 0; i < imageDivs.length; i++) {
  imageDivs[i].addEventListener('load', imageLoaded)
}

function imageLoaded(e) {
  let div = e.target.closest('div');
  div.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+this.src+')';
  div.classList.add('loaded');
  div.removeChild(div.querySelector('img'));
}
```

```css
.container{
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
  background-size: cover;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  transform: translatex(-100%);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image.loaded{
  animation: slideInFromLeft 1s cubic-bezier(.5,0,.3,1) forwards;
}
.image img {
  height: 0;
}

@keyframes slideInFromLeft {
  0% {
    transform: translatex(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translatex(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/honda_civic_type_r_honda_type_r_honda_129270_3840x2160.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

This triggers the animation of a particular `<div>` (if you have more than one) as soon as that image loaded, rather than triggering all of them after **all** images in the page have loaded (if you use `window.load`).

However, this doesn't mean you should load huge resources in your page. Optimizing your images and loading them the right size for current device is a very important step in website optimization. You should use [srcset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images#Resolution_switching_Different_sizes) for this purpose.